# How to say that "watch this movie continuously till the end"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-usage

I am bit confused and lack of words when I am trying to say this. Sometimes when a movie is full of thrill and suspense we should watch it till the end to get the suspense revealed. But due to lack of time or movie length, we don't watch it from the beginning to the end. In this case, how do native speakers express *to watch a movie till the end?*

For example:

> Watch the whole movie in one sitting; or
>
> Watch it till the end; or
>
> something better and quick.

Comment: If it were a book, we would say "can't put it down". An adjective might be _mesmerizing_ .

Comment: Other options include "watch the movie without interruption," "watch the movie without a break," and "watch the movie without a pause."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In one sitting** is fine. According to [Collins Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+sitting) it's a common idiom, meaing:

> If you do something at one sitting or in one sitting, you do not stop doing it until you have finished it.

In your example you could say:

> We did (not) watch the movie in one sitting.

Attribution: Collins COBUILD Idioms Dictionary, 3rd ed.. S.v. "in one sitting." Retrieved July 7 2018 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+sitting